# How to listen to double click event from Autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

How to listen to double click event from Autodesk forge? I am trying to bind the logic into the double click and zoom event. May I know which event shall I listen to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to implement the `ToolInterface` - see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/03/creating-tools-for-the-view-data-api.html) for details:

```
          this.handleDoubleClick = function(event, button) {

              console.log('-------------------');
              console.log('Tool:handleDoubleClick(event, button)');
              console.log(event);
              console.log(button);

              return false;
        };
```

Alternatively subscribe to the double clicks on canvas instead:

```
viewer.canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', e=> {
  //do stuff here
});
```